# Getting area of a US phone number as a substring mvc

Tags: c#, .net, regex, substring

I have a phone number:

```
public string PhoneNumber
{
    get
    {
        return _phoneNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
        _phoneNumber = regexObj.Replace(value, "");
        _phoneNumber = Regex.Replace(_phoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
    }
}
private string _phoneNumber;
```

How can I make `public string Areacode` a substring of PhoneNumber containing the first 3 digits(area code)? I'm using mvc by the way. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you guaranteeing that phone numbers are always assigned in a specific format that is parseable?  Phone numbers can live in dozens of different formats; are these always US phone numbers? Do you have a sample data set to run some tests against?

Comment: Are you asking how to assign the first three digits to another string property when there are ten digits, or the second through fourth digits when there are eleven digits and the first digit is 1? Or do you want to get serious about it?

Comment: The length of the phone number has a maximum of 10 digits (US numbers only) @Cory. As far as data sets go, using "1234567891" should suffice for my purposes.

Comment: @julianc Ok, go right ahead

Comment: Would it just be public string Areacode{get{return _area}set{_area=_phonenumber.Substring(0,3)}} @EdPlunkett? Sorry, I'm just new to all this.

Comment: @julianc you'd set AreaCode in the PhoneNumber setter, whenever PhoneNumber changes. Tgats where you'd call SubString. Never set in a getter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, if all you are looking for is to take the area code in another property, there could be several simple ways, but here is one of them..

```
public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[^\d]");                
            _phoneNumber = regexObj.Replace(value, "");               
            var match = Regex.Match(_phoneNumber,  @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})");
            if(match.Success)
            {
                _phoneNumber = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", match.Groups[1], match.Groups[2], match.Groups[3]);
                this.Areacode = match.Groups[1].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    private string _phoneNumber;

    public string Areacode { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete noob but this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.